# Wordpress Custom URL not loading Post Category in Create New Post Page

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an issue since last months. When I'm trying to use custom url in wordpress permalink setup, in create new post page, categories are not loading. In ajax call, it is saying invalid json data given.
**Here is the permalink setup**[image: Custom Permalink setup]

**Here is the Create new post page output with that settings**
[image: Create New Post view with error]

**Here is the plain permalink setting**
[image: Plain permalink setup]

**Category is loading easily with plain setting**
[image: Category loading with plain permalink setting]

I'm not sure is it wordpress setting issue or theme issue?

My server setting:

PHP version 7.4
Runs on Apache with Nginx in front.
Theme: Newspaper Theme by [tagdiv](https://themeforest.net/item/newspaper/5489609?s_rank=2)

Please help me out.

Comment: I'm using latest wordpress. Everything is updated to latest version. I always keep everything updated.

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue of Nginx. Nginx does not support `.htaccess` file, thats why when you use Nginx as http server with wordpress, you need some modification in Nginx settings for custom url in wordpress.

Here is the explanation and sample code for Nginx setting for wordpress

https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

Hope this might help some one in future.